# How to determine Daylight Saving Time (DST) in Tizen Native Application?

Tags: c, dst, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

Is there any possibility to determine is Daylight Saving Time (DST) now in Tizen Native Application (pure C) for wearable device (Gear S2/S3), because after:

```
time_t rawtime;
time(&rawtime);

struct tm *tm_local;
tm_local = localtime(&rawtime);
```

field `tm_local->tm_isdst` is always `0` (even for DST dates).

Comment: Can you use [Tizen's i18n `Timezone` module](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/4.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__BASE__UTILS__I18N__TIMEZONE__MODULE.html)?

Comment: @MattJohnson Tizen's i18n Timezone module (`i18n_timezone_get_dst_savings()`) did the trick! Please convert your useful comment into answer.

Comment: @MattJohnson Will `i18n_timezone_get_dst_savings()` returns `0` for non DST dates? Or it returns offset constantly for timezone and not depend on current date?

Comment: I don't use this platform at all.  I just found the docs.  I think you want to use `18n_timezone_get_offset_with_date`, passing in `i18n_timezone_create_default()` for the time zone parameter.  Feel free to supply your own answer, I don't need the points. ;)